# Mapping Resolution & fixVersion received via Python JIRA REST API to human-readable values

Tags: python, rest, jira, python-jira

I need to pull information on a long list of JIRA issues that live in a CSV file. I'm using the JIRA REST API in Python in a small script to see what kind of data I can expect to retrieve:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv
import sys
from jira.client import JIRA
*...redacted*

csvfile = list(csv.reader(open(sys.argv[1])))
for row in csvfile:
    r = str(row).strip("'[]'")
    i = jira.issue(r)
    print i.id,i.fields.summary,i.fields.fixVersions,i.fields.resolution,i.fields.resolutiondate
```

The ID (Key), Summary, and Resolution dates are human-readable as expected. The fixVersions and Resolution fields are resources as follows:

```
[<jira.resources.Version object at 0x105096b11>], <jira.resources.Resolution object at 0x105096d91>
```

How do I use the API to get the set of available fixVersions and Resolutions, so that I can populate this correctly in my output CSV?

I understand how JIRA stores these values, but the documentation on the jira-python code doesn't explain how to harness it to grab those base values. I'd be happy to just snag the available fixVersion and Resolution values globally, but the resource info I receive doesn't map to them in an obvious way.

Comment: How about using version.name and resolution.name?

Comment: @mdoar - Yes, I wasn't clear on how to get into the list values, but I think that will work. Testing it tomorrow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User [mdoar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/123802/mdoar) answered this question in his comment:

> How about using version.name and resolution.name?

Answer (score 0):

You can use fixVersion.name and resolution.name to get the string versions of those values.